Junit and Mockito how mock class being instantiated with mocked parameter
I'm not super familiar with mockito. I am trying to mock the results of a class that is being instantiated within another class.
public class TestClass {
    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
        SomethingConfig somethingConfigMock = mock(SomethingConfig.class);
        
        final ClassBeingTested cbt = new ClassBeingTested(
            parameter1,
            parameter2,
            somethingConfigMock
        );
        cbt.getResults();
    }
}

public class ClassBeingTested {

    public ClassBeingTested(parameter1, paramater2, somethingConfig) {
        this.parameter1 = parameter1;
        this.parameter2 = parameter2;
        this.somethingConfig = somethingConfig;
        ...
    }

    public Results getResults() {
        // do lots of stuff
        OtherClassToTest otherClassToTest = new OtherClassToTest(somethingConfig);
        String s = otherClassToTest.getSomeString();
        // do lots of stuff
    }

}

so in this example I just want to expect that once OtherClassBeingTested is instantiated with somethingConfigMock it will return generic results for methods like getSomeString().
In my mind it would look something like
when(new OtherClassToTest(somethingConfigMock)).thenReturn(otherClassToTestMock);
when(otherClassToTestMock.getSomeString()).thenReturn("genericString");

Am I looking at this the wrong way or is there an easy way to do this without significant refactoring?
I have tried just mocking somethingConfigMock but at a certain point i always get a NullPointerException within OtherClassToTest.

You are looking at this the wrong way.

You're mocking SomethingConfig class instance, so this is what you should configure with "when thenReturn" etc. Other classes are real.
OtherClassToTest will eventually call some methods of SomethingConfig instance. This is where your mocking configuration kicks in.
A mock instance with no configuration as in your code currently just returns nulls (and empty collections, I think). Apparently, this is why you get an NPE.
So you need when(somethingConfigMock.aMethodCalledByOtherClass()).thenReturn(somethingYouNeedForATest);.
